# Add link to java JTable?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jtable, jlabel

I have a project that has a JTable. Inside that JTable I have Strings that I used to display the content coming from my MySQL database. Now I have a problem where the last column needs to be an image (or text) that when clicked, it will open a dialog that displays an image related to that database row. I'm using a DefaultTableModel to style, and vectors that add the row into the JTable. I then realized I can't have String and Images inside of a vector - they must all be the same type.

So I switched to JLabel thinking that I can use the text to display, then in the image / text, I could use tooltiptext to get the exact location of the image file. But now my JTable data just displays: `javax.swing.JLabel` instead of the actual text. I'm adding the row to my JTable as follows:

```
for (int j = 0; j < receiptData.size(); j++) {
  receiptTableModel.addRow(receiptData.get(j));
}
```

`receiptTableModel` is a `DefaultTableModel`; `receiptData` is a `Vector<Vector<JLabel>>`.

Is there something I'm overlooking to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have images or any other objects in the table model. Using a `Vector` of `JLabel`s as a row in the table model is a bad idea. In the model we should keep "data"; not UI components.

Try below example. It uses a custom cell renderer and a custom cell editor for the "image" column.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ImageInTable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("blue_star.png");
    ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("red_star.png");

    DefaultTableModel receiptTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {},
        new Object[] {"Number", "Description", "Icon"});

    Vector<Object> row1 = new Vector<>();
    row1.add("1234");
    row1.add("Receipt 1");
    row1.add(icon1);
    receiptTableModel.addRow(row1);

    Vector<Object> row2 = new Vector<>();
    row2.add("5678");
    row2.add("Receipt 2");
    row2.add(icon2);
    receiptTableModel.addRow(row2);

    JTable table = new JTable(receiptTableModel);
    table.setRowHeight(34); // Set row height according to the height of the image
    table.getColumn("Icon").setCellRenderer(new IconRendererAndEditor(table));
    table.getColumn("Icon").setCellEditor(new IconRendererAndEditor(table));

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    f.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class IconRendererAndEditor extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {

  private Icon icon;

  IconRendererAndEditor(JTable table) {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(table, icon);
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    this.icon = (Icon) value;
    setIcon(this.icon);
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                                 int row, int column) {
    this.icon = (Icon) value;
    setIcon(this.icon);
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return this.icon;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void cancelCellEditing() {
  }

  @Override
  public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
  }

  @Override
  public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
  }
}
```

When you run it, it will look like this:

[image]